# How do I make overlapping images clickable; image transparency is getting in the way?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transparency

Please see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j30hb4dz/3/).

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap. What I'm trying to accomplish here is on md+ devices, have a row of 4 diamonds/thumbnails with a second row of 3, all fairly close but not touching. When the user is on a smaller device, the diamonds switch from a row of 2, then a row of 3, then a row of 2. I have the code working fine for this now as you can see on the JS Fiddle, but if you have a cleaner way of doing this without JS please share. :)

My problem arises when I try to make the images clickable, since these are going to be thumbnails I want to use Featherlight (a lightbox alternative as you probably know) so that when the user clicks on a thumbnail I can have a box pop up with a larger image and information about it. I left this out of the JSFiddle and instead used "regular" links for demo purposes. The transparency from these diamond images is the problem. Because the images are so close together, the transparent section of one of these diamonds always overlaps another, making a section of each diamond link to an unintended diamond.

I have tried image mapping and altering the z-index. The overlapping transparency problem persists. Would creating this shape out of CSS work instead (how would I do that)? What solution is there to this? Thank you so much for any help!

HTML:

```
<section class="container-fluid diamonds">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="xsrow1">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 xsright no-padding"><a href="#0"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 no-padding"><a href="#1"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4 xsRow2Margin no-padding"><a href="#2"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4 xsRow2Margin no-padding"><a href="#3"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 mdrow2">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 xsRow2Margin no-padding"><a href="#4"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="xsrow3">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 xsright no-padding"><a href="#5"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 no-padding"><a href="#6"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.no-padding {
    padding: 0!important;
    padding-right: 3px!important;
    padding-left: 3px!important;
    margin: 0!important;
}
.diamonds {
    position: relative;
}
.diamonds img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .xsRow2Margin {
        margin-top:-15.2%!important;
        margin-bottom:-15.2%!important;
    }
    .no-padding {
        padding-right: 2px!important;
        padding-left: 2px!important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .xsrow1 img, .xsrow3 img {
        width: 66%!important;
        height: auto;
    }
    .xsright {
        text-align: right;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .diamonds {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .xsRow2Margin {
        margin-top:-15.9%!important;
        margin-bottom:-15.9%!important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .mdrow2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 51%;
        left:0%;
        padding-left: 3%;
        padding-right: 3%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution . I've placed the anchor tag on top of the image at the center and rotated it by 45degrees. Give highest z-index for the anchor. I've done only one diamond so you might have to do some tweaks with your css.

```css
.img{
height:168px;
  width:168px;

}

.link{
transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    height: 118px;
    width: 118px;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4 xsRow2Margin no-padding"><img class="img" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/o5565j.png" style="
    position: absolute;
"><a href="#3" class="link"></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using absolute numbers in px's, however you gave me an idea with rotating 45 degrees. I wonder if creating the images as squares and rotating them to create the diamonds would fix my problem. I'm going to tweak your code and also try what I just suggested sometime today and see which solution works best. Thank you for your response! :)